# Predefined type microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder is not defined or imported

Tags: c#

I'm using the dynamic keyword in my C# project. I get the below error

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found.

Below is my code and we are using VS 2013 with .NET Framework 4.5.1.

```
dynamic cstmDocProp = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)mScribeShell.ScribeShell.ActiveWordDoc.CustomDocumentProperties;  
string s = String.Empty;
s = Convert.ToString(cstmDocProp[mConstants.g_sPROPERTY_DOCUMENT_INDEX].Value);
```

I have already referred Microsoft.Chasharp DLL and System.Core DLL as suggested in other links.

After referring Microsoft.Csharp DLL I'm getting another error as

> predefined type microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder is not defined or imported.

Comment: If you found Tom's answer helpful, please accept it.

Answer (score 72):

- Right Click on your project and select 'Add reference'
- Select 'Assemblies->Framework' in 'Reference Manager' window.
- Add select **`Microsoft.CSharp.dll`** and click on add.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Worked for me, In my case, I upgraded mvc 4 to mvc5 and this problem came out. Nuget restored a lot of dlls and then this to finish the problem. Thanks.

Comment: All of the Framework assemblies are already referenced - this is the message I get following the steps above. Using a PCL, the type it can't find is System.Object.