# Cannot convert Db-date to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-3.5

I have a date from a database as shown in the image below.
[image: DateTime-image]

However when I convert this value to a `DateTime`-instance I get the error shown below. [image]

However when running the code I get an `InvalidCastException` that the returned value cannot be cast to `DateTime`.

I am using VS2010 on .Net3.5 that´s why I wonder why this library is needed at all.

Within a referenced assembly I´m using IronPython which uses DLR as far as I know. On .Net 3.5 I can use this however when referencing Microsoft.Scripting and Microsoft.Scripting.Core also. I suppose this causes the error in any way. Weird on this is that the code that uses IronPython is not called at all when executing the code producing that exception.

EDIT: For those who can´t believe: the same code works some time querying some rows from the database and returning correct dates. However at one point it throws that exception.

Further EDIT: As you can see on first image `row.GetValue` returns a `dynamic` which is strange as the assembly (ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop) where this code is implemented is also written using .Net 3.5. Furthermore when I go to the definition of that type I get `object get_Value(int Index);` instead of `dynamic`.

Comment: Did you try Convert.ToDateTime() or DateTime.Parse()

Comment: providing some code would be nice, especially your usings and refs

Comment: what you have tried.?

Comment: @KrishnaPS Yields same error.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566887/dynamic-in-the-immediate-window-causes-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-binder-i Looks like you need to use .NET Framework 4 or higher.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Even this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500057/predefined-type-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-is-not-defined-or-imported discusses about the problem

Comment: @KrishnaPS As already mentioned I compile against .NET 3.5, not 4.5.

Comment: have you tried SqlDataReader.GetDatetime Method?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Hey try adding a reference to Microsoft.Csharp.dll in your project!

Comment: Is 'dynamic' only used under certain circumstances?

Comment: @sr28 Circumstances? The signatur is obviously clear: return `object`, no `dynamic` at all.

Comment: @KrishnaPS Even referencing that assembly from my project did not solve the problem. However I´m still confused why it actually should be needed.

Comment: @pengMiao I´m using IronPython 2.6.1003.1

Answer (score 1):

you need at least **.NET framework 4.0** to use `dynamic`. The compiler will allow you to define and assign a `dynamic` variable, but when you trying to do anything with the `dynamic` variable, you will come across this error

```
Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported
```

Please refer to [C# 4.0 and .Net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218245/c-sharp-4-0-and-net-3-5)
for more details. credit goes to that Aaronaught ( which answer that question)

Update:

> on .Net 3.5 I can use this however when referencing Microsoft.Scripting and Microsoft.Scripting.Core also. I suppose this causes the error in any way.

IronPython have their own customized Microsoft.Scripting and Microsoft.Scripting.Core. When you reference those two assemblies again, it will cover up IronPythons' dll and use those official which i believe causing those weird behaviour. Try to remove both reference and see does it helps

Comment: I know that I can use `dynamic` only on 4.0 upwards. However I´m not using the keyowrd as you see within my second update.

Comment: Based on http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/214/how-to-check-if-a-query-returns-data-in-asp-net-web-pages,
 when you use `queryvalue` or `querysingle` it actually return a `dynamic` object

Comment: which version of ironpython you are using?

Comment: @HimBromBeere can you post the code of your row.getValue() or information about any third party library(include nuget package) or assemblies use so that we can dig up mor info?

Comment: The code is shipped within ArcGIS10 for Desktop- However I´m quite sure they do NOT return any dynamic, as the assembly is in use for years now without ever noticing such a behaviour on even .NET 2.0.

Comment: @HimBromBeere sorry i just found i miss a very important information from your question.
the problem is as you suspected : referencing Microsoft.Scripting and Microsoft.Scripting.Core.
Ironpython has its own version of Microsoft.Scripting and Microsoft.Scripting.Core , so when you try to reference the offlcial Microsoft.scipting and microsoft.scripting.core into your project, it may conflict and causes weird behaviour just like your case.
So, please remove the reference.
Hope its help :)

Comment: I replaced the assemblies by those shipped within IronPython but it also changed nothing.

Comment: Obvioulsy you assumed right that the call to `row.Get_Value` actually retusn a `dynamic` instead of an `object`. This made my way, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found some really strange behaviour which explains the exceptions.

First of all the `InvalidCastException` was absolutely right as the call to `row.Get_Value(2)` actually returned `DBNull` which of course cannot be cast to `DateTime`.

Next the value shown in the QuickWatch wasn´t the right one, as VS showed me the whrong line for that exception making me *assume* that the call to `(DateTime) row.Get_Value(2)` caused the error instead of the call to `row.Get_Value(1)` (which preceds the former). The latter however returns `DBNull` as allready mentioned.

Last but not least the messy stuff around with the missing library is obviously caused by ArcGIS itself. As @pengMiao already assumed this call actually returns a `dynamic` (although its signature only mentions `object`). Now QuickWatch isn´t smart enough to directly cast this to whatever the right type is (in my case `DateTime`). However if I write `(DateTime)(object) row.Get_Value(2)` providing a cast to `object` first and then to `DateTime` we get what we want in both, QuickWatch AND executable.

It is still unclear to me why in QuickWatch we get `dynamic { DateTime }` as data-type for the value returned, however it works now.